# Nested async.map in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express

I'm facing one issue while using https://github.com/caolan/async library. I have a situation where I'm using asyc.auto with a function which uses async.map. Now in the callback I get an array of results and in the next function, I need to call db update/insert query. Can I use async.map inside another async.map.

To make things clear, take a look at this:

```
async.auto({
    // other functions
    D: ['A', function(callback, results){
        var resultIds = results.A;
        async.map(resultIds, function(data, cb){
            // do some stuff
        }, function(err, result){
            console.log(err);
            if(err) {
                callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        }); 
    }],
    E: ['D', function(callback, results){
        var resultIds = results.D; // an array of result which contains ids: [1,2,4]
        async.map(resultIds, function(data, cb){
            // Can I use again a async.map here like this
            async.map(data[ids], function(d,cb){
                // do some stuff here
            }, function(err, result){});
        }, function(err, result){
            console.log(err);
            if(err) {
                callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        }); 
    }]
}, function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    if(err) {
        cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, results);
});
```

Is there any better way to handle such scenarios ? I'm mongo for updating/inserting new docs with these ids.

Comment: Why not create all in the backend side? Make a single call from the frontend and on your backend get your id's and update/insert your data

Comment: You can nest as many levels as you want as long as you call the callbacks correctly

Comment: what stuff are you doing in the two `async.map` callbacks in `E`?

Comment: @biancamihai: This is entire backend stuff only...

Comment: @Ben: One doubt, you mentioned that we need to call callbacks correctly...does that mean I need to different callback param for each async.map ? Also, regarding naming of callback params, can I use any name for that ?

Comment: @Robbie: actually first asyc.map is iterating over an array of objects. This object contains a list of string ids which are getting updated/inserted in second async.map. The final callback should contain whether all the updates/inserts are success or not

Comment: @dark_shadow, you don't have to have different param for each async.map and you don't have to name them differently.  The way you name it (cb) for both outer and inner callbacks will just work if you call cb because JS scoping will figure out which one it is.  What I meant was that calling async.map() callback when you in it.  I've seen code that calls  the outer callback (such as E's callback) instead of async.map()'s callback.  My personal preference, I name them differently just to help me and other reading my code.  I would name outer map as mapCb, and next level of async.map() as mapCb1.